# How do I count number of times a sub-string exists in a token C++

Tags: c++, token

So i need to check if a specific sub-string exists in a Token and if it exists add 1 to the variable int a.

String input = "aaabbb#abbb#"

tokenize input

tokens =

```
abbba 
abbbb
```

a exists in both tokens so output should be

```
a:2
```

However my code outputs

```
a:1
a:1
```

If there is only one token with a then it prints

```
a:1
```

If there are no tokens with a such as :

bbb#bbb#

it correctly outputs nothing.

How can i get my code to output

```
a:2
```

and not

```
a:1
a:1
```

---This is my code

main.cpp

```
#include "Tokenizer.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int countSubstring(const std::string& str, const std::string& sub)
{
    if (sub.length() == 0) return 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (size_t offset = str.find(sub); offset != std::string::npos;
     offset = str.find(sub, offset + sub.length()))
    {
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // instanciate Tokenizer class
    Tokenizer str;
    string token;
    string input;
    getline(std::cin , input);
    // set source string with delimiter "#" 
    str.set(input, "#");

    // Tokenizer::next() returns a next available token from source string
    // If it reaches EOS, it returns zero-length string, "".
    while((token = str.next()) != "")
    {
        int a = 0;
        if(countSubstring(token,"a") >= 1)
        { 
           a++;
        }

         cout << "a: " << a << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Tokenizer.h

```
#ifndef TOKENIZER_H
#define TOKENIZER_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

// default delimiter string (space, tab, newline, carriage return, form feed)
const std::string DEFAULT_DELIMITER = "";

class Tokenizer
{
public:
    // ctor/dtor
    Tokenizer();
    Tokenizer(const std::string& str, const std::string& delimiter=DEFAULT_DELIMITER);
    ~Tokenizer();

    // set string and delimiter
    void set(const std::string& str, const std::string& delimiter=DEFAULT_DELIMITER);
    void setString(const std::string& str);             // set source string only
    void setDelimiter(const std::string& delimiter);    // set delimiter string only

    std::string next();                                 // return the next token, return "" if it ends

    std::vector<std::string> split();                   // return array of tokens from current cursor

protected:


private:
    void skipDelimiter();                               // ignore leading delimiters
    bool isDelimiter(char c);                           // check if the current char is delimiter

    std::string buffer;                                 // input string
    std::string token;                                  // output string
    std::string delimiter;                              // delimiter string
    std::string::const_iterator currPos;                // string iterator pointing the current position

};

#endif // TOKENIZER_H
```

Tokenizer.cpp

```
#include "Tokenizer.h"


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// constructor
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Tokenizer::Tokenizer() : buffer(""), token(""), delimiter(DEFAULT_DELIMITER)
{
    currPos = buffer.begin();
}

Tokenizer::Tokenizer(const std::string& str, const std::string& delimiter) : buffer(str), token(""), delimiter(delimiter)
{
    currPos = buffer.begin();
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// destructor
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Tokenizer::~Tokenizer()
{
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// reset string buffer, delimiter and the currsor position
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Tokenizer::set(const std::string& str, const std::string& delimiter)
{
    this->buffer = str;
    this->delimiter = delimiter;
    this->currPos = buffer.begin();
}

void Tokenizer::setString(const std::string& str)
{
    this->buffer = str;
    this->currPos = buffer.begin();
}

void Tokenizer::setDelimiter(const std::string& delimiter)
{
    this->delimiter = delimiter;
    this->currPos = buffer.begin();
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// return the next token
// If cannot find a token anymore, return "".
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
std::string Tokenizer::next()
{
    if(buffer.size() <= 0) return "";           // skip if buffer is empty

    token.clear();                              // reset token string

    this->skipDelimiter();                      // skip leading delimiters

    // append each char to token string until it meets delimiter
    while(currPos != buffer.end() && !isDelimiter(*currPos))
    {
        token += *currPos;
        ++currPos;
    }
    return token;
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// skip ang leading delimiters
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Tokenizer::skipDelimiter()
{
    while(currPos != buffer.end() && isDelimiter(*currPos))
        ++currPos;
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// return true if the current character is delimiter
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
bool Tokenizer::isDelimiter(char c)
{
    return (delimiter.find(c) != std::string::npos);
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// split the input string into multiple tokens
// This function scans tokens from the current cursor position.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
std::vector<std::string> Tokenizer::split()
{
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::string token;
    while((token = this->next()) != "")
    {
        tokens.push_back(token);
    }

    return tokens;
}
```

Also, a is not allowed to be printed if it does not appear in a token.

Comment: I [can't compile your code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12581aca9d86b440) unfortunately. Can you provide us with a [MCVE] pleae.

Comment: if you remove all the blank lines in the code it might become readable

Comment: ^ That on top, yes.

Comment: Correct your code: `int a = countSubstring(token, "a"); if (a > 0) cout << a << endl;`

Comment: @Dan please upvote if you agree with my answer

Comment: This would be a great problem to use to teach yourself how to use the debugger, the problem is incredibly trivial.

Answer (score 1):

A while would work better I think. This is my solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

size_t countSubString(const string& str, const string& sub) {
   size_t ret = 0;
   size_t loc = str.find(sub);
   while (loc != string::npos) {
      ++ret;
      loc = str.find(sub, loc+1);
   }
   return ret;
}

int main() {
   static const char* tokens[] = {"aaa", "aba" };
   for (int i=0; i<2; ++i) {
      cout << tokens[i] << " " << countSubString(tokens[i], "a") << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int countOccurances( const std::string &token, const std::string &substring )    
{
    const size_t token_len = token.length();
    const size_t substring_len = substring.length();        
    if ( substring_len > token_len ) { return 0; }
        if ( substring_len == token_len ) 
            return ((token.compare(substring) == 0) ?  1 : 0); 

    const size_t range = token_len-substring_len;
    size_t counter = 0;
    for (size_t i=0; i <= range; i++) {
        if ( token.compare(i,substring_len,substring) == 0 )
            ++counter;
    }
    return counter;
}

int main () {
    std::string token = "abbb";
    std::string substring = "a";

    std::cout << "Token " << token << " has " << countOccurances(token,substring) << 
    " occurances of " << substring << std::endl;

    token = "abba";
    substring = "a";

    std::cout << "Token " << token << " has " << countOccurances(token,substring) << 
    " occurances of " << substring << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: 'i' does not name a type and "warning: 'auto' changes meaning in C++11; please remove it".

Comment: compile with g++ -std=c++14

Comment: You were not compiling with flags to use C++14.  I have made it backwards compatible now.

Comment: @MustafaOzturk you can edit the answer yourself as you find ways it can be improved.

Comment: @MustafaOzturk also, really? I would think the compiler will optimize a pre or postincrement on a primitive type to the same assembly. They seem equally readable -- C++ seems to prefer pre-increment since there's a meaningful performance difference for iterators but C style is perfectly happy to use post-increment all else equal.

Comment: seems to do the same thing as my current code unless I'm doing something wrong. output : Token abbba has 1 occurances of a, Token abbbb has 1 occurances of a

Comment: @djechlin I'm just being pedantic because OP was being pedantic with my code. Tongue in cheek mostly

Comment: @djechlin that said, ++i will have meaningless performance improvements for an int, but for a more complex object not making a copy of the original object might have some performance gains. Good habit to switch to prefix by default.

Comment: @Dan make sure you run the most recently posted code.

Comment: @MustafaOzturk on gcc 6.2 the ASM output will be exactly the same fpr i++ or ++i

Comment: `#include <string>
int main () {
  for ( size_t i=0; i<10; ++i ) {
  }
}`

Comment: `std::piecewise_construct:
        .zero   1
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], 0
.L3:
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], 9
        ja      .L2
        add     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], 1
        jmp     .L3
.L2:
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
`

Comment: `#include <string>

int main () {
  for ( size_t i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
  }
}`

Comment: `std::piecewise_construct:
        .zero   1
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], 0
.L3:
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], 9
        ja      .L2
        add     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], 1
        jmp     .L3
.L2:
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
`

Comment: @MustafaOzturk paste it in and see for yourself

Comment: @peekay I have the countOccurances function and I am sticking the cout statements in my while loop. now the output is just doubled but im still not getting the total number of occurances in all the tokens.

Comment: @Dan there is no while loop in my solution.  You must not be using the solution I actually posted.  Please upvote my solution.

Comment: @Dan your code originally posted breaks compartmentalization by conflating substring search logic with calling the logic from main.  You need to restructure the solution to search for a substring which should be able to stand on its own and be used in even other programs as well.

Comment: @peekay thanks for trying to help but i guess my question is worded wrong. I need to count if a appears but a token aaaaa and token abababa would together make variable a = 2 because a is present at least once in each token. its kind of hard for me to explain.

Comment: @ChuckNorrris compare `int main () { int i=0; while (i<10) { cout << ++i << endl; } }` vs. the same code in postfix and you'll see a difference. In your example the optimizer threw away the entire for loop. As I said earlier, for an simple unsigned number the difference is one operation, for more complex objects however the change in performance could be significant as the postfix operator requires you to make a copy of the object before you increment it. I'm surprised at your resistance to using prefix. I'd assume a pedantic coder like yourself would prefer to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

The heart of your code is this

```
    int a = 0;
    if(countSubstring(token,"a") >= 1)
    { 
       a++;
    }

    cout << "a: " << a << endl;
```

This code creates a variable called `a` and assigns it the value `0`. Then it calls countSubstring and tests if the return value for being `>= 1`. The return value is then discarded.

If the condition above matched, we increase `a` by 1.

Then we print `a`.

All of the above happens for each iteration of the while loop in which this code sits.

So this code can only ever print `a: 0` or `a: 1`.

This is a shame, because the value you were looking for was returned to you *by countSubstring* yet you chose to discard it.

Your code can be fixed this simply:

```
int count = countSubstring(token, "a");
std::cout << "a: " << count << '\n';
```

As in:

```
while((token = str.next()) != "")
{
    int count = countSubstring(token, "a");
    std::cout << "a: " << count << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't really solve my problem because countSubstring is just used to see if a token contains "a". I'm asking how I can look at a bunch of tokens and check if each one contains at least 1 "a" and for each token that contains at least one  "a" the variable a is incremented so if I have 5 tokens and they all contain at least 1 "a" then I want to print a:5. I worded my question poorly.